# Sending JSON from View to Controller ASP.NET MVC gives null values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a problem with sending JSON data from MVC View to Controller, all I get to Controller is:

[image]

where my JSON I send in Url.Action looks like this: (I create it by my own adding array to array by .push() and then JSON.stringify )

```
[
   [
      {
         "isOrdered":false,
         "orderLineId":"4550",
         "comment":"",
         "orderId":"2789"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "isOrdered":false,
         "orderLineId":"4551",
         "comment":"",
         "orderId":"2789"
      }
   ]
]
```

I use JQuery ajax POST

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("SaveCheckboxesAndComments")",
            data: JSON.stringify(array),
            traditional: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

and my controller:

```
public class JsonData
        {
            public bool IsOrdered { get; set; }
            public string OrderLineId { get; set; }
            public string Comment { get; set; }
            public int OrderId { get; set; }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SaveCheckboxesAndComments(List<JsonData> jsonArray)
        {...
```

Should I change something in my class JsonData or in JS to get values? Because somehow the "frame"  is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to try:

1. Open up your Network tab in the dev console and check out the details of the `POST` request to make sure that the url is correct and that the JSON being sent is what you expect
2. Decorate the `JsonData` class with a `[DataContract]` attribute, and each property with a `[DataMember(Name = "Name")]` attribute - to make sure that you don't run into issues with casing (the property names in the class are all capitalized, and your json starts with lower case for each).
3. It looks like you have an extra set of external `[` `]` brackets on your generated Json. So while your action is expecting `List<JsonData> jsonArray`, it is being sent `List<List<JsonData> jsonArray>`. See how it works removing the outermost square brackets from the json being sent.

Comment: What was the issue in the end?

Comment: I used your 2. and 3. option and I had wrong sent object, it was all about extra [ ]